# how forward link from a inline button to another chat in pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-api, pyrogram

I use a user bot in pyrogram to save links from a bot to a personal channel.  I use this code:

```
def forwardlik(mensaje)
    if "Link!" in mensaje.text:
        mensaje.forward(ids["channel"])
```

But now the bot it's sending the link with a button inline and I don't know how to make the program press the button and send only the link to my channel.
Someone can help me?

Example pictures:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  First, your function looks like it takes `mensaje` as its argument and not `message`.  Second, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for help on how to clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome..yes the program use the message..i Will find the post rigth now...was the autocorrector

Comment: Fixed now..sorry for that

Comment: please consider attaching a screenshot of a sample bot conversation to give us some hint what kind of interaction it is

Comment: thanks for the advice...i updated now with screenshot of a sample

Answer (score 0):

```
@Client.on_message(Filters.chat("<--botid-->>"))
async def foo(c, message):
    # The below condition will take the link from the first button and if it exists it will print the link
    if x:=message.reply_markup["inline_keyboard"][0][0].url:
        print(x)
```

you can take the var x and forward it to another channel

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but...

You can use the [Message](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/Message) bound method [`click()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/bound-methods/Message.click) to get a string in case the button is a url.